# Row Locks in Partitioned Aurora MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, locking, mysql-8.0, aws-aurora

I'm experiencing many row locks in a AWS Aurora AWS MySQL

```
MySQL version=8.0
Aurora Version=3.04.0
```

The table is pretty big close to 1 Billion rows. The table is partitioned in 24 partitions based on the created at column.

In one of the production issue we found 26 rows have been locked.

```
---TRANSACTION 19670234666, ACTIVE 299 sec
53 lock struct(s), heap size 8312, 26 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 7015846, OS thread handle 70369603010432, query id 12207362320 
IP username
```

We update only one row of the table using `id` condition, we do not pass `created_at` in the update query.

What could have been the reason of 26 rows being locked?

DB query

```
UPDATE OrderEntity e SET e.state = :state, e.metadata= :metadata WHERE e.id = :id
```

Table Structure

```
id: BIGINIT
state: INT
metadata: TEXT
created_at: DATETIME
updated_at: DATETIME
...

Primary Key: id, created_at
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't include the "partition key" in the `WHERE` clause, the query must open every partition.  Then it will look for the `id` in question.  If that id is "off the end" (or beginning) of the partition, then that "gap" is locked to prevent another query from suddenly inserting a row with that id.

If you would like to discuss workarounds, please provide more details on why it it partitioned (perhaps 23 month's worth plus periodic purging?)  Also what other queries are often used.

(No, I can't explain "26" instead of "24" or "25".)